# “Thinking in Scala" if I have a Java/C++ background?

Tags: java, scala, architecture

I'm familiar with developing server-side applications in Java, but now I'd like to start using Scala. Can you describe the paradigm shift that is necessary? Here are a few questions that might help you frame an answer:

1. How do I architect and design web applications differently? What is
   the biggest difference?
2. What should I stop doing/using; What should I start doing/using
   instead?
3. Are there any client-side considerations/restrictions?

I'm not looking for a detailed comparison between Java and Scala.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297592/why-are-there-so-many-upvotes-for-this-question

Comment: I've tried learning languages by difference from other languages, and it has never worked for me. Now a start with a beginner book in the language I'm learning. That explains everything in terms of the way you should think for the new language.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I appreciate your comment.. But I still think a detailed answer to this question is feasible and possible and that will surely help future visitors of the thread..

Comment: @harshtuna - this would be closed on Programmers for being too broad.

Comment: Before voting for close ... please see the meta post http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297592/why-are-there-so-many-upvotes-for-this-question

Comment: @Amit "SO shouldn't venture into hosting blog posts just because it has a higher PageRank than alternative blogging outlets." "Usefulness to the community is not a reason..."

Comment: @harshtuna Yeah, my answer on meta shouldn't carry much weight in any case: it was outvoted & the question was closed as opinion-based. So...not very conclusive evidence of consensus on meta. I think Amit might be playing devil's advocate here, expecting this to be closed having posted it only to prove a point. I hope the request is genuine, though, since I'd hate to see people pouring effort into answers to a fake question. (I'd suggest continued discussion along these lines be on meta.)

Comment: @Frank Actually case is reversed, I indeed wanted to post this question since last few days but was sure it will be closed immediately and than I saw that old JS/ AngularJS question and when discussed on meta. I thought why not try if I can some good answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key difference between Scala and Java is Scala's use of functional programming.

1. For web applications, you will use different frameworks. Play is currently the most popular flavour. It feels similar to MVC work in other frameworks but leans more towards functional purity (though most Play apps are far from being pure)
2. You should stop thinking in terms of mutating fields in memory and think about data flows of immutable values. Do not use a `var`, when you can do it with a `val`. Loops will mostly be replaced with higher order constructs like `map` and `fold`. Avoid nulls, and use `Option`s instead.
3. Assuming a web client side, no. Unless you want to compile Scala to JS. Then the same stuff applies.

Learning wise, I would start with [Twitter Scala school](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/), then once you grok that, I recommend the book [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/). I think these two resources will guide you in the FP direction, as opposed to writing Java-style programs with new syntax. Then, find the right spot in the OOP/FP scale that suits the problem at hand.

Comment: There's also the coursera courses for Scala, and subsequently, Reactive Programming (in Scala).

Comment: Interestingly, Scala is, at its heart, a purely object-oriented language, much more object-oriented and much more pure than Java. The focus on functional programming is actually not in the language but in the libraries and (most importantly) the community.

Comment: The language has a lot of features to directly support ideas only found in functional programming. Monads, higher-kinded types, etc. So FP support in Scala is deliberate, not a side effect (punny) of the community.

OO and functional programming are orthogonal, and scala supports both working together. BUT a lot of mutability-oriented OO practices and patterns simply disappear

Comment: I don't mean to say FP in Scala is an accident. Quite the opposite, it is an incredible testament to the genius of Martin Odersky having designed a language that works so well for so many different styles of programming with such few language constructs. Unifying functions, objects and modules into a single construct (objects), for example. Higher-kinded types are about type safety and abstraction, as are monads. Abstraction is not unique to FP, it is in fact at the very core of OO as well, and type safety is a goal for any typed language be it FP or OO. Really, function literals and the …

Comment: … `apply` syntax sugar are the only features for FP Scala has. Everything else is in the libraries: the `FunctionN` traits, the focus on referential transparency, all the methods like `map` taking functions as arguments. I find such an approach to language design refreshing, as opposed to ever bolting on feature after feature.